# SetARPINSTALLLOCATION wrong value

Tags: wix, wix3.5

```
<Custom Action="SetARPINSTALLLOCATION" After="InstallValidate">NOT (REMOVE="ALL" or REMOVE="ProgramFiles")</Custom>
```

I have this custom action called in InstallSequence, action that must populate in upgrade INSTALLDIR from registry, and this custom action is called in fresh install also.

In majority of cases this action, for fresh install, return one location from local machine, and the setup works without issues, but on a customer machine the value returned is \SomeDir\ and the setup faills.

How could I use this custom action to work correctly?

Comment: The problem seems to be in your custom action. Did you try debugging it to see why it sets an invalid path?

Comment: I don't know how to debug, is a custom action from WIX.

Comment: From the command line run your msi with the following "msiexec /l*v msilog.txt /i myInstaller.msi" and this will output a log file in same folder at the msi file.  Here you should be able to see what's going on in the install procedure

Comment: If this is a DLL custom Action, check that you haven't got some dependency on the DLL that's missing on the customer system and which makes it fail. Use depends.exe on the CA DLL to check your dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some analysis I found that the functions works correctly, but the system contained an invalid registry entry, and for that value the result of SetARPINSTALLLOCATION was a wrong value.

The wrong value in registry was generated by the existence of record InstallLocation directly on uninstall registry key, without any guid like parent.

Thanks.